# Load Sendmail log files to pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to analyse a lot of long Sendmail log files some of them gzipped, I'm trying with pandas,

the lines have the format :

```
    2019-02-04T17:41:06.957332-08:00 server1 sendmail[1945]: x151f6Ng001945: from=<xxxxxxxxx@domain1.com>, size=20946, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<ZZZZZZZZZZZ>, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA, tls_verify=NONE, auth=NONE, relay=server1 [127.0.0.1]
    2019-02-04T17:41:06.990091-08:00 server1 sendmail[1955]: x151f6Ng001945: to=<xxxxxxxxx@domain2.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, tls_verify=NONE, pri=140946, relay=server2. [IP_2], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as 43tnNL6jtyz6p3vf)
```

the first columns, date server are separated by  space, but the rest of the line is separated by  ", " (comma space) , and the number of fields is variable, 
my idea is to separate in columns by the space,and on the last field later search for specific text, to create new columns,

I try with `sep=r',(?!\s)'`  to do not use  comma space as a separator, but don't works

some ideas

Answer (score 0):

One approach is the following: use `sed` on the command line to cut up the data into 5 columns.

`sed -e s/" "/", "/1  test.txt | sed -e s/" "/", "/2  | sed -e s/" "/", "/3 | sed -e s/" "/", "/4 | sed -e s/" "/"\""/5 | sed -e s/$/\"/ > test_5cols.csv`

This puts commas in the first 4 spaces. The other data in the 5th column is all "mixed" and do not come in the same order.

```
2019-02-04T17:41:06.957332-08:00, server1, sendmail[1945]:, x151f6Ng001945:, from=<xxxxxxxxx@domain1.com>,"size=20946, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<ZZZZZZZZZZZ>, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA, tls_verify=NONE, auth=NONE, relay=server1 [127.0.0.1]"
2019-02-04T17:41:06.990091-08:00, server1, sendmail[1955]:, x151f6Ng001945:, to=<xxxxxxxxx@domain2.com>,"delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, tls_verify=NONE, pri=140946, relay=server2. [IP_2], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as 43tnNL6jtyz6p3vf)"
```

You can then use pandas read_csv to pull it into a df and then rename the columns.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I load the file by line in  a Dataset and create new columns extracting the specific fields that I need, was easier that read_csv options